# I Can't Open My Wordpress Login Page

Tags: wordpress

I am having an odd problem. When I try to login to my site using Wordpress to this address:

http://theexpeditioner.com/wordpress/wp-login.php

I get the following error:

Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET):

I am also sometimes getting Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown error.

This happens on all my browsers from my computer. I have tried clearing the cache, disabling firewalls, turning off virus shields, etc... I don't have any proxies. I have tried disabling plugins, etc...

The odd thing is that I can open that page using my phone over LTE (and I can open it in other computers). So it seems to be an issue with my computer?

Any ideas?

Comment: I know it's probably not all that helpful, but I can access that page just fine as well. Could be an issue with your firewall or antivirus based on a quick Google search of the error text.

Comment: That's the only page that doesn't open? So, any other public website opens fine?

Comment: Jordan: Yes, every other page opens fine. Matthew Darnell: Yes, that's what I thought. I've tried disabling them all and it didn't help. Maybe if I unistall them . . .

Comment: Have you tried to disable Antivirus software? Looking on the web people got that Error 103 due to that.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Jordan: Yes, this appeared to be a simple server error by my hosting company. Sorry, I'm not sure if was supposed to delete this question or not.

Comment: Now this url worked in my side.

Answer (score 0):

Error 101 is an issue with permissions. (usually) Try using a different browser, or reinstalling the one you are already using.

If you want to manually change permissions, go to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local in Windows Explorer. Then, go to the properties of the Temp folder. Then, go to the Security tab. Select your user, then make sure that you have all the necessary access in the lower box.

Comment: I am also getting a Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): now.

Comment: Oh. 103 could be a bunch of things. One solution is to type the URL with HTTPS instead of HTTP. Another solution is to restart your wireless router. You should also make sure your firewalls aren't blocking it (but with WordPress, I highly doubt it). Google wrote something about fixing it with Command Prompt, but that only helps with Chrome. Here's a link: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136678 .  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but this problem is happening on all browsers. I'm now suspecting it's a router issue. I'm going to attempt to restart it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you want more help.